# append ms access data in tables from multi user environment to sql server table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an MS application where data gets saved in a database in different systems. Would like to move the data in all the access files which are in different systems into a single table in SQL server. I tried to link tables but with the link tables i am able to append a single row at a single time. I am actually saving multiple rows into the access database at a single click. Multiple rows are not being transferred to SQL server by linking tables

Split Database Option: The split Database option is not supporting multiple users login at the same time and enter data. The DB crashes.

Upon click of a button or close a form the migration activity to be initiated and should not overwrite the rows entered by other users. I know this requirement is complex and as of now i donot have any code written

Please help me with the approach to sort this out and let me know if any information required

Answer (score 0):

A quick method: using a local temp table, save everything you wish to upload into that local table. Then use that localtable as the basis for your sql append query.

Comment: Thanks Erin.  I used it but the append query is taking too long to execute since no of users are executing the query at the  same time. Is there any way to run the querries in a queue

Comment: Not that I know of. You can, however, schedule using VBA. Depending on the number of users/size of query you can schedule the query to run  every x minutes or a x time every hour